# Display BLOB from mySQL with php

Tags: php, html, mysql, blob

After I managed it to insert blobs into my db I'm trying to Display a BLOB from MySQL.

This is the getImage.php:

```
<?php
  $id = $_GET['id'];
  // do some validation here to ensure id is safe

  $link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root");
  mysql_select_db("user_auth_tutorial");
  $sql = "SELECT image FROM testblob WHERE image_id='$id''";
  $result = mysql_query("$sql");
  $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
  mysql_close($link);
  header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
  echo $row['image'];
?>
```

Here the HTML:

```
<img src="getImage.php?id=1" width="200" height="200" />
```

This is the content of my db:
[image: table testblob]

Unfortunately Dev-Tools throw an internal server 500 Error.
Browser-Output:
[image: Screenshot]

Can anybody tell me what I do wrong?

Thank you so much!

Comment: First of all, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You shouldn't use the deprecated `mysql_*` methods. Use parameterized queries with PDO or mysqli instead. Secondly, your SQL statement has too many `'` characters at the end.

Comment: Thank you for the hint - removing the double ' did not solve the problem.

Comment: It sounds like you need to [turn on error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php) and find out what the problem is.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($row['image']).'"/>';
```